# Can't copy Vertex Group

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups, pose-mode, vertex-weights

I can't copy my selected Vertex Group because I cannot select the button.
I would copy the Weight Painted Vertex Group to the other side but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the arrow dropdown menu to create a copy of the already painted vertex group, mirror it if necessary, delete the target vertex group and rename the copy as the deleted target.

[image]